# Is this a jQuery bug? $.post vs $.ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

UPDATE: my code may be confusing and contain errors. But here is what I'm trying to do with both $.ajax and $.post
----I want to send JSON to php and receive plain text. But $_POST is empty<-why?-----

I found the $_POST to be empty if I use $.ajax, but contains the right content when using $.post
Update: Requirement--
I need to use a JSON request. But problem is $_POST is empty in php, see Var_dump
This is my script

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Ajax_example.php",
                data: {"field": $("#field").val()},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                success: function(msg){
                    alert("NEW DATA:"+msg);
                }
            });
    /*      $.post("Ajax_example.php", {"field": $("#field").val()}, 
                    function(msg){
                        alert("NEW DATA:"+msg);
                    });*/
            return false;
        })

    });
    </script>
```

This is my php

```
    <?php

    echo var_dump($_POST);


    ?>
```

With the above, $.post portion are comments. With the $.ajax portion running, it alerts out only "NEW DATA:"
But If I do it the other way around, I will get whatever I put in #field

Comment: I think you need to set the content type for $.post as well.

Comment: This is a very confusing question based on the comments below...I don't think anyone knows what you actually want (respectfully including you...)

Answer (score 4):

You're using `$.ajax()` incorrectly. The `data` parameter to `$.ajax` is wrapped in a string. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ajax_example.php",
    data: {field: $("#field").val() },
    success: function(msg){
        alert("NEW DATA:"+msg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Now the code is incorrect since the wrong contentType. OP just use json instead of regular form-urlencoded to make a request.

Comment: @bjornd: I need to use a content type other than contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",?

Comment: @William - don't use `contentType`, use `dataType: 'json'` (see my answer)

Comment: @William provided that the server replies with the right `Content-Type` header, you don't need to specify `dataType` at all. You almost never need to specify `contentType`.

Comment: @Matt Ball---these all are for testing out an API which "By default, it uses (jQuery/Zepto).ajax to make a RESTful JSON request"(Backbone.js)...that's why I thought I should use contentType to force a JSON request. I'm not really building a form. Does that make sense?

Comment: _"Does that make sense?"_ Not to me. AFAIK, `contentType` doesn't "force" anything. It just specifies the [HTTP request header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_headers#Requests). Anyway, "not really building a form" is not a reason to avoid the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding. It's **just a MIME type.**

Comment: @Matt Ball, so what is a JSON request if contentType: doesn't have to be "application/json;

Comment: @William what do you mean by "a JSON request?" Do you just want to `POST` some JSON to the server? The default `ContentType` (form URL encoded) is _fine_.

Comment: @Matt Ball...this is from the Backbone.js API I'm trying to use Backbone.sync is the function that Backbone calls every time it attempts to read or save a model to the server. By default, it uses (jQuery/Zepto).ajax to make a RESTful JSON request. What's your interpretation

Answer (score 1):

In the section which you say is not working, you're going through great lengths to make a string for your data, but in the section you say is working you are passing an object literal (preferred). Fix the $.ajax section to pass an object literal as the `data` option.

You're also passing a `contentType` option, but no `dataType` option.  Use either of the versions in the code block below:

```
$( function()
{
    $( '#submit' ).click( function( e )
    {
        /**
          THIS
         */
        $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Ajax_example.php',
            data: {
                field: $( '#field' ).val()
            }
            success: function( msg )
            {
                alert( 'NEW DATA:' + msg );
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        } );

        /**
          IS THE SAME AS THIS
         */
        $.post( // type implied in method name
            // url
            'Ajax_example.php',
            // data
            {
                field: $( '#field' ).val()
            },
            // success
            function( msg )
            {
                alert( 'NEW DATA:' + msg );
            },
            // dataType
            'json'
        );

        /**
          DON'T RETURN FALSE...CONTROL YOUR EVENT INSTEAD
         */
        e.preventDefault();
    } );
} );
```

Comment: If you provide a `dataType` to `$.post()`, it's the **last** argument. Also, what's wrong with using `return false;` instead of `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: @JAAulde--according to jQuery, dataType is the type of content you expect back from the server, in this case in plain text. So your code doesn't work. Moreover, as I said the requirement is it must be a JSON request. That's why I did   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8". Thanks! But any other thoughts?

Comment: @Matt - you are quite right on the param order.  I was editing to align the options to `.ajax` with the params to `.post` and moved the wrong one. As for `return false;`, I believe it is too broad of an operation and that you should specifically control your events. ( http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/ )

Comment: @William, ok, I guess i was terribly confused by your question and your very odd PHP (with code mixed from various trials.)  You want to send JSON to PHP and receive back plain text? In what field should the transmitted JSON be contained? Or do you simply wan the entire POST body to be a JSON string? Based on the chunk of code you said was working, it does not appear that you are trying to send JSON. (are you aware of the difference between JSON and the object literal syntax in JS?)

Comment: @JAAulde, I want to send JSON to php and receive plain text. I was able to get the JSON in php://input. But $_POST is empty<-why?.

Comment: @JAAulde, I got it to work without specifying contentType...and now it says in the browswer Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded. My data is now data: {"field": $('#field').val()}. So is this a JSON request or a plain text form?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in $receive variable, not $_POST. Try:

```
<?php
    $receive=file_get_contents('php://input');
    $receive=json_decode($receive, TRUE);
    echo $receive['field'];
?>
```

Comment: I am testing both options of receiving data. I got the $receive to work. But not the $_POST